# Chosing a different value for NaN entries from appending DataFrames with different columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am concatenating multiple months of `csv's` where newer, more recent versions have additional columns. As a result, putting them all together fills certain rows of certain columns with `NaN`.

The issue with this behavior is that it mixes these `NaN`s with true null entries from the data set which need to be easily distinguishable.

My only solution as of now is to replace the original NaNs with a unique string, concatenate the csv's, replace the new NaNs with a second unique string, replace the first unique string with NaN.

Given the amount of data I am processing, this is a very inefficient solution. I thought there was some way to determine how Panda's `DataFrame` fill these entries but couldn't find anything on it.

Updated example:

```
A B  
1 NaN  
2 3
```

And append

```
A B C  
1 2 3
```

Gives

```
A B C  
1 NaN NaN  
2 3 NaN  
1 2 3
```

But I want

```
A B C  
1 NaN 'predated'  
2 3 'predated'  
1 2 3
```

Comment: You need to be a bit more specific, please add some small examples of your data and examples on what you want to achieve.

Comment: updated an example of what is happening and what I would like to have happen

Answer (score 2):

In case you have a core set of columns, as here represented by `df1`, you could apply `.fillna()` to the `.difference()` between the core set and any new columns in more recent `DataFrames`.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data={'A': [1, 2], 'B': [np.nan, 3]})

   A   B
0  1 NaN
1  2   3

df2 = pd.DataFrame(data={'A': 1, 'B': 2, 'C': 3}, index=[0])

   A  B  C
0  1  2  3

df = pd.concat([df1, df2], ignore_index=True)

new_cols = df2.columns.difference(df1.columns).tolist()
df[new_cols] = df[new_cols].fillna(value='predated')

   A   B         C
0  1 NaN  predated
1  2   3  predated
2  1   2         3
```

Comment: The issue with this is that it will replace all NaN values in that column. If the 3 is NaN then it would become "predated" and would not be distinguishable.

However I got the solution to work by adding column C to df1 with NaN values, using fillna, and then appending.